# Connect to Mongo database using Python and CosmosClient

Tags: python, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I have an application that uses MongoDB written in Python, and I'm working on migrating it to Azure Cosmos.
I've already created an account and prepared a client that I'm reading with

`cosmos_client = CosmosClient(url, key)`

With this I can connect to the client, but now I want to connect to a Mongodb inside, using its connection string.

So, I'd want something like

`mongo_client = cosmos_client.getMongoDatabase(connection_string)`

Is there any function to do that? I can't find anything in the docs

Comment: Looks like you're mixing things up. `CosmosClient` is for the SQL API. And the SQL API doesn't have a "MongoDB inside" - you need to actually create a Cosmos DB instance with the MongoDB API, and then just use whatever MongoDB SDK you like to use - there is no Cosmos DB client library for MongoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make this work changing my calls to the `asyncio` library to use async within the library `from azure.cosmos.aio import CosmosClient`

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a way to connect to MongoDB in Azure Cosmos DB using Python. You can use the PyMongo driver to communicate with the Azure Cosmos DB’s API for MongoDB.

1. Get the MongoDB connection string by using the quick start1.
2. Install PyMongo using pip2.
3. Use the following code snippet to connect to
   your MongoDB instance:

   from pymongo import MongoClient

   client = MongoClient()
   db = client.

You can then use the db object to interact with your MongoDB instance.

Comment: I am not sure, but it should work. But, make sure to make a **copy of your data** just in case.

Comment: Also, I would recommend that you test the code in a test environment before deploying it to your production application.

Comment: The problem with pymongo is that it is giving me trouble when running async queries towards cosmos. Actually, that's my biggest issue. I could already connect with pymongo and asunción but when changed to the cosmos client It stopped working. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No idea. I don't know why your cosmos client stops. Sorry.