# Migration to Cosmos Azure on Python, with async queries

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, pymongo

I have a Python application that uses pymongo as driver, and the asyncio library to perform asynchronous queries.

I'm trying to migrate to Cosmos Azure and the synchronous queries are running correctly but the queries run with asyncio don't. Is there a library similar to pymongo that I could use to handle this issue?

Comment: Please edit to show the queries you're running, along with the issues you're having. As written, there's really no way of knowing the specific problem. Also, it's unclear why you tagged this as [tag:pymongo] if you're not using pymongo (or what the issue would be with pymongo)

Comment: Ok it looks like this question is essentially a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76534034/272109) you also posted. Please don't post duplicates. As I explained in a comment on the other question, it appears that you're mixing the APIs and SDKs in a way that can't be done - you have to create a MongoDB API instance of Cosmos DB, and then use whatever MongoDB SDK you want to use (in this case, `pymongo`). You can't just spin up the native SQL API of Cosmos DB and use that with MongoDB SDKs