# Azure Cosmos fails with SQL-like queries

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I'm integrating my Python application with Mongo to run it migrating that Mongo to Cosmos in Azure.

I have some asynchronous queries, and for them I'm using library `from.cosmos.aio import CosmosClient` and following the examples here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/samples/examples_async.py

I've created my database and inserted a collection and a document with the Azure UI for this test.

Similarly to that example code in the azure github repo I obtained my database:

`database = client.get_database_client(database=database_name)`

My container:

`container = database.get_container_client(container_name)`

and prepared a query

```
async for item in container.query_items(
                query='SELECT * FROM mycollection m WHERE m.id = myid',
                enable_cross_partition_query=True,
        ):
            print(json.dumps(item, indent=True))
```

and finally I'm running it with

`asyncio.run(exampleAsync()))`

where `exampleAsync` is the async function where all the database/collection/queries were placed.

I'm getting this error:

```
Message: Sql api is not supported for this database account
ActivityId: db9855dc-056e-4814-951d-de655a182475, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0
```

It is true that Mongo is not a SQL-like database, but all the examples that I've seen point to run the queries like this.
What am I missing here?
Is there maybe another functions or similar to handle Mongo or no-SQL databases requests?

Comment: Correct:  MongoDB does not speak SQL.   Cosmos *does* speak SQL but the error code suggests that it's not a syntax problem (it recognizes the SQL) but rather a permissions/entitlements issue.

Comment: My database, on this status before finishing the migration has only one user, the one that was created when I set It up on the UI. So, now Ineed to add more permissions to that one? Can that be done using the UI or do I need something else? @BuzzMoschetti

Comment: Sorry ; not a Cosmos export.   I changed the tags in order to draw more Cosmos eyes.

Comment: This is now the third question you've asked about this, and I've already explained it in a comment under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76534034/272109): you're trying to mix the SQL API and MongoDB API.

Comment: So how should I do this then? I'm a bit confused now. Could you point me to an example of a correct asynchronous  query for a MongoDb in Cosmos? All the examples I see mix the aio client with SQL-like queries. How should this be done?

Comment: The first step is to read up on Cosmos DB's different APIs (native SQL, MongoDB, Cassandra, and Gremlin). And see that they are all different. When you create your instance, you must create a specific type. `cosmos.aio` only works with a SQL API instance and won't work with a MongoDB instance.

Answer (score 0):

`Sql api is not supported for this database account` means your Account type is not a NoSQL account.

The SDK you are using it's the Python NoSQL SDK, only meant to be used with NoSQL accounts.

If you created a Cosmos DB Mongo account, it cannot be used with these SDKs, they need to be used with MongoDB drivers.

Comment: I was using motor as an async library but it wasn't working for the database in Azure, that's why I tried this. Can I use that one, maybe with changes on the configuration? What driver would you suggest for asynchronous queries?

Comment: Or do you mean that I have to change something in the configuration of the account, maybe in the UI, to make these kind of queries available?

Comment: Please refrain from asking the same question multiple times. I already explained to you (in a comment under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76534034/272109)) that you can't mix-and-match APIs.